# How to solve cannot find symbol method addOnTabSelectedListener?

Tags: java, android, dependencies, android-tablayout

How to solve cannot find symbol method addOnTabSelectedListener in android studio? I have tried adding dependencies still error persists

Below is my buid.gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.parse.starter"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

Log
Android resource compilation failed

```
C:\Users\JEFF\Desktop\Instagram\ParseStarterProject\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2979: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_scrollFlags' with config ''.
C:\Users\JEFF\Desktop\Instagram\ParseStarterProject\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2979: error: resource previously defined here.
C:\Users\JEFF\Desktop\Instagram\ParseStarterProject\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3059: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/behavior_peekHeight' with config ''.
C:\Users\JEFF\Desktop\Instagram\ParseStarterProject\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3059: error: resource previously defined here.
C:\Users\JEFF\Desktop\Instagram\ParseStarterProject\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3108: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_collapseMode' with config ''.
C:\Users\JEFF\Desktop\Instagram\ParseStarterProject\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3108: error: resource previously defined here.
C:\Users\JEFF\Desktop\Instagram\ParseStarterProject\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3230: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_anchorGravity' with config ''.
C:\Users\JEFF\Desktop\Instagram\ParseStarterProject\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3230: error: resource previously defined here.
```

Comment: Provided everything else is correct, the `TabLayout#addOnTabSelectedListener()` method wasn't added until version 24.0.0 of the support libraries. If you can't upgrade, for whatever reason, you can either use the `setOnTabSelectedListener()` method instead, or roll your own implementation of `addOnTabSelectedListener()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

use

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"
```

**Real use case:**

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/gray"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/blue"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/blue"
    android:background="@color/white"             
/>
```

and instead of the Support library it is better to use [androidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx)